# Can username and password prompt be taken from the user to invoke the app on google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am developing a Google Assistant app which will be accessible to only registered users. I do not wish to go through the process of account linking. I am prompting the user for account ID and password which authenticates the user from my backend and is working fine while i am testing it. Can it face any guideline issue when i publish it?

Comment: as you want to make authentication probably you can go for voice recognition to authenticate the user rather than typical username and password.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a very bad idea from both a design and a security view point and is indeed prohibited by the [Actions on Google policy](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#privacy_and_security):

> Don't collect authentication data via the conversational interface (text or speech).